# React Error - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to call some function from another file in my react component and I've searched about this and it does not makes sense why is this throws an error for me.

I have multiple components where I need to redirect a user to a postID and I know i can make that function inside the specific component, but it's kind of ugly to have same functions in every components, more likely if I have more than 1 helper function.

Can someone help me?

My component Main.js

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { redirectToPostID } from '../helper/helper';

function Main() {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="content">
                <div className="lists">
                    <div className="post" onClick={(e) => redirectToPostID(1)}>
                        <span>Post 1</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="post" onClick={(e) => redirectToPostID(2)}>
                        <span>Post 2</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Outlet />
        </>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Helper.js file:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export function redirectToPostID(id) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    navigate(`post/${id}`);
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call hooks in the body of a function component, not in an onClick callback. If you were doing this inline, you would do it like:

```
function Main() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // ...
  <div className="post" onClick={(e) => navigate(`post/${1}`)}/>
  // ...
  <div className="post" onClick={(e) => navigate(`post/${2}`)}/>
}
```

If you want to make a reusable hook, the hooks can again only be called in the body of the component, so it would look something like this:

```
export function useRedirectToPostID() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const redirectToPostID = function(id) {
    navigate(`post/${id}`);
  }
  return redirectToPostID
}

// used like:
function Main() {
  const redirectToPostID = useRedirectToPostID();
  // ...
  <div className="post" onClick={(e) => redirectToPostID(1)}/>
  // ...
  <div className="post" onClick={(e) => redirectToPostID(2)}/>
}
```

Comment: I get same error when using second code